# wxwidgets wx/wx.h not found

Tags: c++, cmake, wxwidgets

I am writing a sample "Hello World" code from the wxWidgets documentation. I had installed the wxwidgets from source with gtk configured. After that I had installed it system wide. Below were the CLI commands entered by me:

```
mkdir gtk-build
cd gtk-build
../configure –-with-gtk
make
sudo su
make install
ldconfig
exit
cd samples
make
```

The executables in the samples directory work fine for me. Also I see that a wx directory is created in usr/local/include where I see a "wx.h" file. But when I include it in my .cpp file and compile using g++, I get following error:

```
hello.cpp:1:9: fatal error: wx/wx.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include<wx/wx.h>
```

Do I need to link the wx folder while compiling in any way?
How to do that? Also if I want to use a CMakeList to build and compile the code, what arguments apart from `add executable` will I need to run the basic "hello world" code using wxWidgets?

The code is used from official documentation as follows:

```
#include<wx/wx.h>
class myApp : public wxApp{
    public:
        bool OnInit() override;

};

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);

class MyFrame : public wxFrame{
public:
    MyFrame();
    
private:
    void OnHello(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event);

};

bool MyAPP::OnInit(){
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame();
    frame->Show();
    return true;
}

enum{
    ID_Hello = 1
};

MyFrame::MyFrame() : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, "Hello World"){
    wxMenu *menuFile = new wxMenu;
    menuFile->Append(ID_Hello, "&Hello...\tCtrl-H", "Hello string is shown in status bar");
    menuFile->AppendSeparator();
    menuFile->Append(wxID_EXIT);
    
    xwMenu *menuHelp = new wxMenu;
    menuHelp->Append(wxID_ABOUT);
    
    wxMenuBar *menuBar = new wxMenuBar;
    menuBar->Append(menuFile, "&File");
    menuBar->Append(menuHelp, "&Help");
    
    SetMenuBar(menuBar);
    CreateStatusBar();
    SetStatusText("Welcome to widgets");
    
    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &MyFrame::OnHello, this, ID_Hello);
    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &MyFrame::OnExit, this, wxID_EXIT);
    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &MyFrame::OnAbout, this, wxID_ABOUT);
    }
    
void myFrame::OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event){
    Close(true);
}


void myFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event){
    wxMessageBox("About Hello World!", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION);
}


void myFrame::OnHello(wxCommandEvent event){
    wxLogMessage("Hello world from widgets");
}
```

I am compiling the code using `CMakeList.txt` as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Basic)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
add_executable(base hello.cpp)
target_include_directories(base PUBLIC "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")
```

I am performing an out of source build using command `cmake --build .`

Comment: Compile command?

Comment: @sweenish add_executable(test hello.cpp) and the cmake--build .

Comment: I missed that you're using cmake. Given that this is a build issue, the `CMakeLists.txt` seems relevant. [edit] your question.

Comment: But here's a link that might provide you with whatever is missing. https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/CMake

Comment: And just to erase all doubt, outline your entire process of using cmake to build your code.

Comment: @sweenish added CMakeList in the edited question

Comment: I don't see `find_package(wxWidgets ...` anywhere in your code.

Comment: Your compiler does not look in /usr/local/include by default. But you should use the shipped CMake configuration file as @arrowd said.

Comment: @DushyantPatil, please look at the minimal sample directory which provides a sa.ple CMake file for building it.

Comment: This repo includes a wxWidgets starter package for Windows, Linux and macOS using cmake. This will save you time getting started: https://github.com/jhanley-com/jhanley-wxwidgets

Answer (score 0):

I found I had  to repeat the WXCXXFLAGS in my Makefile.

```
WXCXX      := $(shell wx-config --cxx)
WXCXXFLAGS := $(shell wx-config --cxxflags)

.cpp.o:
    $(WXCXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(WXCXXFLAGS) $(WXCXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```